# req.session is undefined when running on Heroku(RedisToGo adds-on) but available when using redistogo url locally

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, redis, redistogo

I've deployed my front-end(React with Typescript) and backend (Nodejs with Typescript) to Heroku separately. I'm using `express-session` and `connect-redis` to maintain the user session, for which I'm using an external Redis service called Redistogo.

When I run my apps locally, `req.session` is present, and upon authenticating the user during login, I'm able to set the user's session in `req.session.user`. However, when running the **backend on Heroku** in the exact same way, `req.session` remains `undefined`.

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      this.app.set('trust proxy', 1) 
      const rtg   = url.parse(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL);
      const redisClient = redis.createClient(rtg.port, rtg.hostname);
      redisClient.auth(rtg.auth.split(":")[1]);


      this.app.use(session({
        name: 'random_pur',
        store: new RedisStore({
            redisClient
        }),
        secret: 'meow',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
          secure: false,
          sameSite: false,
          maxAge: 36000000,
          httpOnly: false,
        }
      }));
    }
```

So I'm not sure what I'm missing here - it doesn't give any problems on localhost. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!